# Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm having an error when I run my project. I want to create an if statement if the textbox1 is empty.My code is like this:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" DELETE from Records WHERE ([Student ID]='" + textBox1.Text + "')", con);
        MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted!", "Information ... ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

        textBox1.Text = " ";

        if (textBox1.Text = " ") 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Student ID", "Delete Failed",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

The error is on texbox1.Text = " "

Comment: Did you mean `textBox1.Text == " "`? Using `==` you **compare**, using `=` you **assign**.

Comment: try using string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()

Comment: Even without having compilation error, your code is totally meaningless as you assign the text yourself.

Comment: I think the compareing is wrong, it must be ==

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if (textBox1.Text = " ")
```

to

```
if (textBox1.Text == " ")
```

[`=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) is *assignment operator* but [`==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) is *equality operator*.

Like;

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" DELETE from Records WHERE [Student ID] = @studentID", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", textBox1.Text);
MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted!", "Information ... ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

textBox1.Text = " ";

if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter Student ID", "Delete Failed",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

And you should always use [*parameterized queries*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html), this kind of codes are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

And using [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) method is much more logical.

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only
>   of white-space characters.

By the way, since you assingning your text yourself, this two lines are meaningles..

```
textBox1.Text = " ";

if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
```

Comment: I have another problem. When I enter empty value or nothing in textbox1. The messagebox appears are Data Deleted and after that another message box will appear saying that Please enter student ID.

Comment: @JvCam That's normal because if yout `textBox1` is _empty_, `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)` returns `true` and that's why your if statements works.

Comment: But I enter an empty value it should show only the Messagebox "Please enter student ID" . The messagebox "Data deleted should not be show.

Answer (score 6):

This is the source of your problem:
`if (textBox1.Text = " ")`

`=` is the assignment operator. You want to use `==` for comparison.

Another option is to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. That will return true if the string is `null`, `""`, or any amount of whitespace.

E.g.
`if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))`

As an aside, your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Please use parameterized queries.

Comment: thanks for your answers. sorry for this question im just a newbie in programming

Comment: @JvCam We all started out as newbies! Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing for equality with `=`, which sets a value.

Instead you need to use the equality operator, `==`.

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" DELETE from Records WHERE ([Student ID]='" + textBox1.Text + "')", con);
        MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted!", "Information ... ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

        textBox1.Text = " "; 

        if (textBox1.Text == " ") 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Student ID", "Delete Failed",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
if(textBox1.Text.trim()=="")
{

 MessageBox.Show("Please enter Student ID", "Delete Failed",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);       
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();}
```

this also Handle whitspace " " .